# Ditaa source code evaluated with no result

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, debugging

The code below evaluated successfully but ~/Downloads/foo.png is empty. A look at the downloads folder shows that no file has been generated. What went wrong?

```
#+begin_src ditaa :file ~/Downloads/foo.png

    +--------+   +-------+    +-------+
    |        | --+ ditaa +--> |       |
    |  Text  |   +-------+    |diagram|
    |Document|   |!magic!|    |       |
    |     {d}|   |       |    |       |
    +---+----+   +-------+    +-------+
        :                         ^
        |       Lots of work      |
        +-------------------------+
#+end_src

#+results:
[[file:~/Downloads/foo.png]]
```

The same diagram, when `ditaa` is called from terminal, produces an output in 6 secs.

```
ditaa diagram.txt sample.png

ditaa version 0.11, Copyright (C) 2004--2017  Efstathios (Stathis) Sideris

Running with options:
Reading file: diagram.txt
Rendering to file: sample.png
Done in 6sec
```

---

## ORG version

[image]

## *Messages*

```
executing Ditaa code block...
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /usr/local/bin/ditaa  /var/folders/rw/rpr418x91h13ysbc6k7fzj240000gn/T/babel-6iUieC/ditaa-lD3wxu /Users/satibodhi/Downloads/foo.png
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /usr/local/bin/ditaa
Code block evaluation complete.
```

Seems like this has something to do with `homebrew` aliasing `java -jar ditaa.jar` to `ditaa`.

```
$ ditaa
usage: java -jar ditaa.jar <INPFILE> [OUTFILE] [-A] [-b <BACKGROUND>] [-d]
       [-E] [-e <ENCODING>] [-h] [--help] [-o] [-r] [-S] [-s <SCALE>]
       [--svg] [--svg-font-url <FONT>] [-T] [-t <TABS>] [-v] [-W]
```

Comment: FWIW, it works fine for me with Org mode version 9.2.3 (release_9.2.3-387-ga41e99). Edit the question and add the version of org-mode (`M-x org-version` will give you that information). Does your `*Messages*` buffer show anything suspicious?

Comment: You can customize `org-ditaa-jar-path` to point to the jar that is working. What does `/usr/local/bin/ditaa` look like?

Comment: It's a symlink to the `../Cellar` path. `$ ls -la ditaa
lrwxr-xr-x  1 satibodhi  admin  32 Jun 21 04:41 ditaa -> ../Cellar/ditaa/0.11.0/bin/ditaa`. This is not a jar file either.

Comment: `/var/folders/rw/rpr418x91h13ysbc6k7fzj240000gn/T/babel-6iUieC/ditaa-lD3wxu` This portion of the executed code seems weird to me.

Comment: Well. just find the jar file, make `org-ditaa-jar-path` point to it and you'll be all set.

Comment: There is no jar file. `org-ditaa-jar-path` can only be directed to `/usr/local/bin/ditaa`, which is aliased as `java -jar ditaa.jar`.

Comment: Of course there is, otherwise the alias would not work.

Comment: Can yoiu post your solution as the answer and accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solved:

Opening the above `ditaa` file in Emacs showed the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec java  -jar /usr/local/Cellar/ditaa/0.11.0/libexec/ditaa-0.11.0-standalone.jar "$@"
```

The above code was evaluated successfully after setting `org-ditaa-jar-path` to `/usr/local/Cellar/ditaa/0.11.0/libexec/ditaa-0.11.0-standalone.jar`.

Comment: This saved me some debugging! Cheers!